# Block access to Express routes until route has finished

Tags: javascript, express

I have a route in my Express REST-API that does some db actions. I would like to block all other calls made to the REST-API until the actions in that route have finished.

So when this route is accessed no other routes can be accessed until update-db-state finishes.

```
router.put('/update-db-state', (req, res) => {
  ... does a buch of database related stuff.
});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why you would want to do this is confusing... but the easiest way is to create a global middleware that does the check.

Comment: you could exploit state to set a flag and unset it when done. While flag is set all routes (or whichever) return an error page or whatever you wish to show while being unavailable

Comment: @kemicofa I need to enforce a working method. People must first insert and make any required changes before they are allowed to retrieve the data for analyzing it. So I need to make sure no reads occur of the data while it is being modified.

Comment: I agree with @kemicofa, seems like there is a different underlying problem that could / should be solved by asking a different question (which could be "How can I enforce a certain workflow").

Answer (score 1):

While it sounds like there is an architectural issue here and I suggest you review the goal you are trying to achieve, you can do something like the following:

```
let lock = false;
router.put('/update-db-state', (req, res) => {
   if (lock) {
       // send a res.end and return or do whatever you need like use a timeout etc etc
   }
   // when starting you process
   lock = true;
   ... does a buch of database related stuff.
   // when complete
   lock = false;
});
```

Once again, I suggest you review the decision to do this as, but here is a simple example to demonstrate.

Comment: I think better if lock is stored in request state (or even db) than being global and applicable to all users regardless if they edit their data